# kernel methods in Python

Tags: python, graph, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Referring to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15798/how-to-calculate-a-gaussian-kernel-effectively-in-numpy , a solution is provided for calculating the precomputed kernel matrix.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
X = loaddata() # this is an NxD matrix, where N is number of items and D its dimensions
pairwise_dists = squareform(pdist(X, 'euclidean'))
K = scip.exp(pairwise_dists / s**2)
```

How one can implement the above Guassin kernel, if the input is a weighted adjacency matrix for a directed graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have your distance matrix, you could simply apply

```
K = scip.exp(YOUR_DISTANCE_HERE / s**2)
```

However, it may no longer **be a kernel**. Not all "similarity scores" are valid kernels. If your distances is a valid **Mahalanobis distance** then you have a guarantee, that everything will be ok. In case of "any" distance - anything can happen.

Usinig invalid kernel may lead to:

1. Optimization process crash
2. Finding suboptimal solutions (bad solutions)
3. Doing **anything**, there are completely no guarantees.

Maybe you should consider **[graph kernels](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/vishwanathan10a/vishwanathan10a.pdf)** which are somewhat strongly related to the gaussian kernel and the heat diffusion